# Why Mule Esb starts slowly?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Collegues, could anybody suggest why Mule on Anypoint studio starts so slowly (more than 1 minute):

> 15.07.2015 **11:21:48.649** INFO  DefaultMuleApplication:193 - 
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   + Initializing app 'myApp'                  +
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   15.07.2015 **11:22:58.779** WARN  JdkVersionUtils:265 - We are looking into adding support for this JDK version. Use it at your own risk.
>   15.07.2015 11:22:58.802 INFO  AbstractLifecycleManager:193 - Initialising RegistryBroker
>   15.07.2015 11:22:59.046 INFO  MuleArtifactContext:193 - Refreshing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@313b2ea6: startup date [Wed
>   Jul 15 11:22:59 MSK 2015]; root of context hierarchy 
>   bla bla bla
>
> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   + Starting app 'mayawebservices'                      +
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   15.07.2015 11:23:04.708 INFO  QueueXaResourceManager:193 - Starting ResourceManager
>   15.07.2015 11:23:04.708 INFO  QueueXaResourceManager:193 - Started ResourceManager
>   15.07.2015 11:23:04.746 INFO  HttpConnector:193 - Connected: HttpConnector  bla bla bla

One week ago it starts much more faster.

**UPDATE 1**

1. Anypoint Studio October 2014 Release Version: 4.1.1 Build Id: 201411041003
2. Mule Server 3.5.0
3. JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
4. I use only one app.
5. On stanalone Esb app is deploying faster.
6. Also i use Maven

Comment: Were you using the same JDK one week ago? Was the Mule application the same size one week ago?

Answer (score 0):

The version of Studio that you are using it's a bit out of date.

I know there has been improvements in the way that Studio launches de ESB, so
one thing I would recommend it's to update Studio to 5.2.0 or if you want to keep your copy of Studio you can do a fresh download, install the ESB 3.5.0, import the project and try again.

Hope this fixes your issue.